# Converting binary from string in node.js - which encoding to use?

Tags: node.js

I have a node.js code which receives a [command + data] via UDP (dgram) and creates an S3 bucket file in AWS.
Problem is, since the command + data is separated with a '|' character, I have to convert to string to apply `split()` and separate the command and the data. Then I pass this data to `S3Bucket.putObject` which creates a file with that data. The data is binary so it might contain non-ASCII characters such as `0xE5` (dec 224).

But when I check the created file, it contains a sequence like `0xEF 0xBF 0xBD` replacing the original, so I guess this is the consequence of converting the data from binary (buffer in dgram) to string.
I tried to convert the data back to buffer using `Buffer.from('binary')` and others encodings, but so far I haven't get it right...

How can I solve this problem? What would be the right way to accomplish this?

Comment: Don't do any string conversion. Just start by finding the | in the binary data and then split.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to convert to string:

```
let idx     = buffer.indexOf('|');
let command = buffer.slice(0, idx);
let data    = buffer.slice(idx + 1);
```